# Async Waiting for Function 1 to Finish before running function 2

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the Correct Async Usage here to get `FetchJoke()` to finish before letting `openDialog()` Run

```
async getrandomJoke(query: string){
      
      this.fetchJoke(query);
      
      this.openDialog();
    }
```

**Update:**

The issue is :   `randomJoke: any;` Is undefined by the time it gets to `openDialog()` even with the await keyword

See below:

```
async getrandomJoke(query: string)
 {
      await this.fetchJoke(query);

      console.log(this.randomJoke + "var"); //Undefined.
    
      this.openDialog();
 }
```

```
  fetchJoke(query: string){
       this.apiService.randomJoke(query).subscribe(
        (data => 
          { 
             this.randomJoke = data;
             console.log(this.randomJoke + "varinside");//[Object object]
          }))
    }
```

No Values are getting sent through to Dialog(). As It seems to run before `Fetchjoke()`Is finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `fetchJoke` return a promise :

```
 fetchJoke(query: string){
       return firstValueFrom(this.apiService.randomJoke(query))
 }
```

Then `await` it !

```
async getrandomJoke(query: string){
  const joke =  await this.fetchJoke(query); // will wait for fetchJoke to finish to continue 
  this.openDialog(joke);
}
```

Comment: Going to update my question as I this is correct but doesnt fix my issue

Comment: @OnceUponATime Please see my update, you need to return a promise in your function

Comment: ah! makes a bit more sense to me now thank you Mat!

Answer (score 0):

You should use await in this case:

```
async getrandomJoke(query: string){
      await this.fetchJoke(query);      
      this.openDialog();
}
```